# Xamarin.Forms - How to select item from its containing ListView with ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, observablecollection, xamarin-binding

I have an `ListView` bound to an `ObservableCollection<ItemID>` as shown. When I click a **Delete** button it calls `DeleteButton_Clicked` correctly but then cannot access the objects. I need to delete object and then change the `Scan.Text` property. Thank you for any help.

[image: List with items]

The `ItemID` class is defined here:

```
public class ItemID
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

This is code that's giving me trouble:

```
private void DeleteButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ItemID items = MyList.SelectedItem as ItemID;
        
    Items.Remove(items);
    MyList.SelectedItem = null;
    Scan.Text = items.Value.ToString(); // it doesn't work
}
```

The Scan button creates an object and also changes the Scan.Text:

```
private async void ButtonScanDefault_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ZXingScannerPage scanPage;
    scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();

    scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) =>
    {
        scanPage.IsScanning = false;

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
            await DisplayAlert("Scanned Barcode", result.Text, "OK");


            Scan.Text = SumCost(Cost_Product(result.Text));

            var item = new ItemID()
            {
                Name = "Name_ID:" + " " + result.Text,
                Age = "Age:" + " " + Cost_Product(result.Text),
                Value = Cost_Product(result.Text)
            };
            Items.Add(item);

        });
    };
    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(scanPage);
}
```

XAML

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            x:Name="MyList">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid Margin="10">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />

                    <Button Clicked="DeleteButton_Clicked"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Padding="30,10"
                            Text="Delete"
                            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                            BackgroundColor="Black"
                            TextColor="White" />
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what could be the problem: In your `DeleteButton_Clicked` you  rely on the `SelectedItem` property of `MyList`. However, clicking the **Delete** button does *not* automatically select that list item.  The way to determine the correct item to delete is to look at the `BindingContext` property of the button that sent the delete click, and cast this object to `ItemID`.

```
private void DeleteButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // The sender is the button you clicked
    Button button = (Button)sender;

    // The binding context of the button IS the
    // item associated with the button.
    ItemID item = (ItemID)button.BindingContext;
    Items.Remove(item);

    // Now you can adjust the Scan.Text however you want.
    // THIS IS JUST AN EXAMPLE
    ItemID defaultScanItem = Items.FirstOrDefault();
    if (defaultScanItem == null)
    {
        Scan.Text = $"[Deleted {item.Name}]";
    }
    else
    {
        Scan.Text = $"[Deleted {item.Name}] Scan {defaultScanItem.Name}";
    }
}
```

**Before and after delete**

[image: Before and after delete]